# git ssh connections are being refused by the server whilst http connection work fine

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, git-extensions

So I lately made my return to gitlab to start hosting my own repositories again, but I ran into a rather unusual problem.

On my last usage of the program v6.4-stable everything worked fine, however now I've upgraded to v.8.1-stable and the http connection works fine when I try to push my stuff to the server. But when I try to use the SSH connection everthing goes bananas.

Here's how I've configured my git extensions:

[image]

When I hit "Test SSH verbinding" (Test SSH connection) I get the following message:

[image]

but when I use PLINK to test the very same connection this is shown to me instead:

[image]

I must be doing something wrong as git extensions keeps throwing the connection refused error

I really hope someone can give me any pointers on what I might have done wrong so any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

I managed to clone using git in my command prompt so I guess this is really a bug introduced by git extensions.

Edit 2:

Used Sourcetree instead of Git Extensions and got it working. I'll report this to the authors of the Git extensions program. Thanks for your time!

Comment: This is reported as an issue here https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/2932

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug or an unimplemented feature of the Git Extensions program.